# Issue using HTML Buttons - Cursor and Alignment

Tags: html, wordpress

Having a couple of issues, looking for a quick fix.  I'm using html in wordpress.

1 - All of my links have no hand cursor when hovering over any of the links..the arrow remains.  Anyone know how to resolve this> I'm using the following code:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/img/floorplans/1 Bed/PH1/FUSE-1Bed-520.pdf"   
style="cursor: pointer;">       
<button type="button">Model #08<br />
```

2 - By default, every button is on a separate line.  I would like to put 3, 4 or even 5 images per line.  Is there a quick way in order to align the boxes on to a single line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the cursor problem try this:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/img/floorplans/1 Bed/PH1/FUSE-1Bed-520.pdf">       
<button type="button" style="cursor: pointer;">Model #08</button>
```

Your links do have the pointer attribute but not the buttons, you could even add this CSS instead:

```
a button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And as for the buttons going on a new line each time make sure that the HTML for them is all on a single line or else WordPress will automatically add paragraph and break tags.

Comment: Both worked, much appreciated for the quick response!